# Retrieving a list from Content Type field in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm sort of new to Drupal 7.

I am using Drupal Form API and I need to use a drop-down showing a list of states via the `mymodule_forms` hook.

```
$form['work_state'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Work State'),
  '#type' => 'select',
  ...
);
```

I already have a list of states defined in a Content Type field.

How would one go around loading the Content Type (ie: forms_stipend) and retrieving the field (ie: field_states).  After that is retrieved, I can start populating the available list of states into the code shown above.

Thanks in advance for your help as they're *always* appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your field is a list type, you can grab the allowed values from the field using the [`field_info_field()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_field/7) function:

```
$info = field_info_field('field_states');
$options = $info['settings']['allowed_values'];

$form['work_state'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Work State'),
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => $options
);
```

Comment: That worked.  You saved me hours of looking all over for this on Google (it hasn't been helpful in the area of Drupal).  Many, many thanks!  I would give you 100 points if I could. :)